# How to avoid a set of values (collected in .so callback calls) from pointing to same address?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
// compile with: g++ 1.cc -o test  -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -lgthread-2.0
// or g++ 1.cc -o testq -lglib-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include/ -lgthread-2.0c


#include <glib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
int counter;
GAsyncQueue *q;

typedef struct MyStruct {
int foo;
char *data;
} *MyStructPtr;

gpointer looper(gpointer data) {
        g_thread_init(NULL);
        while (1) {
                while (g_async_queue_length(q) > 0) {
                        MyStructPtr xtransport;
                        xtransport = new struct MyStruct;
                        xtransport = (MyStructPtr)g_async_queue_try_pop(q);

 // The actual code is acting as weird, as if we have here, xtransport->data = last_text_value_ever_received;
                        std::cout << "str # " << xtransport->foo << ":" << xtransport->data << ":str\n";
                }
        }
}
void adder(char *data) {
        char *processedData;
        // someExternalAPICallToprocessData(data, &processeddata);
        processedData = (char *)data;
        MyStructPtr dtransport;
        dtransport = new struct MyStruct;

        dtransport->data = processedData;//processeddata;
        dtransport->foo = ++counter;

        g_async_queue_push(q, (gpointer*) dtransport);
}
int main() {
        GThread *l;
        g_thread_init(NULL);
        q = g_async_queue_new();
        l = g_thread_create(looper, NULL, FALSE, NULL);
        sleep(2);
        char *t;
        t = strdupa("1111");
        adder(t);
        t = strdupa("222");
        adder(t);
        sleep (5);
}
```

This is a working lab mockup of some larger project. On the project, a strange behavior is noticed;

instead of main(), we're sitting in a callback function, that gets some data from a system component. Trying to print (e.g. cout) that data before putting to queues, can get something like:

> N1 (in Callback): aaaabbbbcccc
>   N2 (in Callback): bbbbaaaacccc.

Same, if the access to (newly set pointer ) dtransport->data is made in a same code where it was created (mainloop/callback function)t; that's fine.

But can't get the correct value of the first elements in the queue! Data fields is always the same - accessing the collected data via queue, can get only the value that was set in last callback; evil pointer hell supposed!

> str #1: bbbbaaaacccc.
>   str #2: bbbbaaaacccc.

Callback function is defined as:

```
int someExternalAPICallToprocessData(...., unsigned char ** data);
```

It returns data's length, and ** - returns pointer to pointer? So it is address problem.

The question is, **would that
 someExternalAPICallTOprocessData() fill &processeddata with a pointer to a fixed address storing only the data of last call**?
How to get a copy of char* being returned and safely put it into MyStruct ?Note, that a next function uses offsets...

```
process(dequeued->data);
void process(char *data) {
 my *ptr = NULL;
 ptr = data + SOME_SIZE_CONST
...
}
```

And somehow, memcpy'ng the content of processedData seems to segfault the .so library which contains someExternalAPICallTOprocessData(). In the mockup context, it is the end of adder(); in the real context it is end of callback function to kernel networking stuff; so funny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does that
>   someExternalAPICallTOprocessData()
>   would fill &processeddata with a fixed
>   address of data per each call

This is a little difficult to parse, but were it "could someexternalApi(&data) set data to be the same address on each call", then yes, it could. I have no idea what the "someExternalApi..." is, however, you have to consult its documentation.

You can handle this by using `strdup` on the returned `processedData`, or by changing `MyStruct::data` to a `std::string` (which would take the burden of correctly deleting the string off you).

Comment: Is there any way to return char * from std::string, so another function can access transport->data as: ptr_data_fragment = transport->data + offset?

Comment: @mhambra `std::string.c_str()`?

Answer (score 0):

looks like your push/pop stack is not thread safe. Imagine, when you push the struct onto the queue, it copies the foo first (and increments the # of items on the stack), that causes the while loop to pop the data from the stack, and *then* the data gets copied. oops.

The answer in this case, is to make sure that all reads and writes to the stack are atomic - stick a mutex or critical section around all calls to it.

Comment: The doc (http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html#g-async-queue-try-pop) says: Asynchronous queues are an exception from most other GLib data structures, as they can be used simultaneously from multiple threads without explicit locking and they bring their own builtin reference counting. This is because the nature of an asynchronous queue is that it will always be used by at least 2 concurrent threads.